# AWS create a larger EBS volume from a Snapshot and specify the number of iNodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, inode, ext4

I have an EBS volume (ext4) mounted as root. 
I would like to both increase the size of the EBS volume, but more importantly increase/set the number of iNodes in it.
However, when creating a volume from a snapshot, I have an option to set the size, but nowhere to specify the number of desired iNodes. My volume should have a large number of iNodes, to support many small files.

How this can be done, when creating a volume out of an existing snapshot?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem

Comment: That's when you have an empty volume (you need to format it). What do you do in AWS when you create a volume from snapshot?

Comment: The accepted answer says "I'm afraid that you need to back-up your data, and create new filesystem, and restore your data."

Comment: Yes, but there must a better way. After all, that's what Amazon does. If you have a 16GB snapshot and you create a new 32 volume out of that 16GB - that's what is happening in the background. Now, when Amazon creates that new volume, it could give us an option to set the number of iNodes, couldn't it?

Comment: They could. They **don't**, to my knowledge.